# Как развернуть веб приложение?

Tags: java, spring-boot, развертывание

Написал я свое первое веб приложение (писал на Spring Boot). Запускаю на localhost - все работает как надо. Теперь хочу развернуть его у себя на работе,чтоб мой ноут выступал в виде сервера и все работники моей организации могли пользовать этим приложением с своего рабочего места через браузер. Прошу посоветовать откуда начинать, возможно ссылки, уроки, документация. Буду признателен за любую информацию.

Comment: Локально вы можете поднять только у себя на рабочем месте. Чтобы это было на production, вам нужно выкупить хостинг, после чего настроить удаленную машину, как вам надо(как минимум java), после чего залить через ssh свой проект и запустить его удаленно.

Comment: Мне пока нужно только локально. Как я это вижу сейчас. Установить TomCat, закинуть в папку webapps мой варник и запустить сервер TomCar. После этого работники моей компании смогут заходить по адресу типа 10.244.2.1/index.html?

Comment: все вы верно видите

Comment: Вам нужно сеть настраивать, после этого, возможно vpn, для того, чтобы остальные не смогли зайти по сети

Comment: @AndriiTorzhkov так вроде речь о локалке. Все что надо уже настроено. Достаточно лишь знать айпишник машины на которой крутится Томкат, ну и фаервол на ней настроить.

Comment: А может собрать jar файл да запускай просто его? Это же Spring Boot. К чему эти томкаты всякие. Поищите как собирать джарку для бута

Comment: Конечно, под SpringBoot уже есть tomcat и его не надо отдельно настраивать, просто запускать либо jar файл в демон режиме, либюо в докер контейнере.

Comment: Всем спасибо, дайте кто-то ответ чтоб закрыть вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сервер, поставляемый в Spring Boot из коробки - вполне подойдет для ваших нужд.

Все, что нужно:

1. Скомпилировать код в один большой jar (`mvn clean install`, если вы используете maven)
2. Запустить jar файл: `java -jar ...youfilename.jar`

Более подробно (а также другие варианты) можно найти тут: https://spring.io/blog/2014/03/07/deploying-spring-boot-applications

Comment: Также добавлю, что нужно отключить брандмауэр для частной сети, чтоб другие могли отправлять запросы по локалке.